# Redirecting with .htaccess depending if string is one word or a sentence

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .php file that receives a language code, and a sentence:

```
domain.com/sentence.php?lang=en&sentence=the house is big
```

Also, this is my current .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^sentence/([a-z]{2,3})/([^/]{3,})$ /sentence.php?lang=$1&sentence=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So if the user goes to:

```
domain.com/sentences/en/the+house+is+big
```

...it will be processed fine. The issue right now, is this: If the sentence contains one word only (no spaces, dots, commas, !?, etc), then it should be processed by a different word.php instead of sentence.php; e.g.:

```
domain.com/sentences/en/house
```

That last url request should be processed by word.php

I know I could easily verify that inside sentence.php, but I think is better if I handle it via .htaccess. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteRule ^sentence/([a-z]{2,3})/(\w{3,})/?$ /word.php?lang=$1&sentence=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^sentence/([a-z]{2,3})/([^/]{3,})$ /sentence.php?lang=$1&sentence=$2 [QSA,L]
```

First regex pattern is `\w{3,}` which will route `domain.com/sentences/en/house` to `word.php` and remaining ones with more than one word will route to `sentence.php`.